# Lista de URLs permitidas con wildcard en el input del visitante

Tags: php

En mi formulario me gustaría que el visitante pueda ingresar en un campo cualquier URL que sea test.com o test2.com (wildcard), por ejemplo test.com/loquesea.

Tengo lo siguiente en PHP:

```
$allowedsites = array(
    'http://test.com/*',
    'http://test2.com/*',
);

if(in_array($longlink, $allowedsites)) {
    $error = "The URL is in the array!";
}else{
    $error = "The URL doesn't exists in the array.";
    include ("crear.php");
    exit;
}
```

He probado sin el * y con *, no me ha funcionado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` busca una coincidencia exacta, si intentas evaluar variaciones de la cadena necesitas expresiones regulares.

```
$patron = '/^http:[s]?\/\/test[a-z0-9]*\.com\/[a-z]*$/';
$url = 'http://test.com/';

preg_match($patron, $url);
```